# Search icon doesnt appear in autocomplete search

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I created this autocomplete search which searches in my mysql database.
Here is my code:

```html
<div class="search-bar">
  <div class="ui-widget">
    <input id="skills" class="search1" placeholder="Cerca un tipo di marca">
    <input type="submit" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the database connection:

```
<?php 
    $dbHost='localhost';
    $dbUsername='root';
    $dbPassword='evolvia2016';
    $dbName='codexworld';

    $db=new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);

    //get search term 
    $searchTerm=$_GET['term']; 

    //get matched data from skills table 
    $query=$db->query("SELECT * FROM skills WHERE skill LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY skill ASC");
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row['skill'];
    }
    //return json data 
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

The problem is that the submit button or  the search icon(zoom) doesnt appear in here.I created this:

```
 <input type="submit" value="">
```

to output the search icon but nothing apperas except a textbox which works well. So the autocomplete is ok except the search icon. Can someone help me ?Have I done something wrong in my code?Thanks!

Comment: Have tried to add fixed height and width for submit button? CSS example: `input[type="submit"] { width: 22px; height: 22px; display: block; }`

Comment: Assigning a value of `""` will result in a very narrow button with no text

Comment: search icon? unclear what you are referring too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An snippet with search icon for you, instead of **input type="submit"** use **button** to stylize then.

```
<html>

  <head>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.2" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="custom-search-input">
          <div class="input-group col-md-12">
            <input type="text" class="  search-query form-control" placeholder="Search" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">
                <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
              </button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```